# Why does After Effects shear my last frame in a loop?

Tags: after-effects

Following the short tutorial [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNGA-QyQ4rk) to make a loop in After Effects using time remapping and the loopOut() expression I encountered some odd behaviour.
In the tutorial it is mentioned that when this method is used a black frame appears between the loops. To remedy this problem one needs to create a new time remapping keyframe the frame before the last one and then delete the last one. This should give a smooth loop.
However, instead of the black frame my frame gets "sheared" as shown below:

Normal frame:
[image]
Sheared frame:
[image]
How can I get a loop using (preferably using loopOut) and not get a sheared frame in the loop? I'm using After Effects CS5.5 on Mountain Lion 10.8.3.

Comment: This seems very odd.  Are you sure this isn't a problem with the source file?  How was the source originally developed?

Comment: I am applying the time remapping to a pre-comp containing three layers with identical content. The content is a jpeg sequence of 5 frames, looped 10 times (through `interpret -> loop`). I have three layers, one of them is the main image, the other two are masking the sides of the image with the same content. Playing the pre-comp without time remapping works fine.

Comment: Any chance you could post the project files somewhere that we could take a look at them.  The behavior seems very odd.

Comment: I've uploaded it here: http://www.mediafire.com/?837pzj72hpd5z9r
The behaviour seems to revert to a black frame instead of a sheared frame after a restart of AE. However, if I replace the last keyframe in the new session, the sheared frame is present again.

Comment: Yeah, the black frame is more what I would expect.  The shearing is very odd behavior.

Comment: It does appear to be a bug.  I was unable to reproduce the problem on the Windows version of CS6 and the loop appears to work fine for me.  I unfortunately had to uninstall CS5.5 when I installed CS6, so I can't test on the Windows version of CS 5.5.  Your keyframe for the loop was off by one frame (you were looping on 1:04 instead of 1:05 (your video ends on 1:06)) but that shouldn't cause the problem you are seeing.

Comment: Oh, one last thought, have you tried removing the de-gitter effect?  That may be trying to blend between the jumping frames.  I didn't have a matching effect so I had to disable that.  That's the only difference I had with my trial run (other than the different platform and AE version.)

Comment: "Toggle hold keyframe" couple frames before the last worked for me.